# numpy ctypes "dynamic module does not define init function" error if not recompiled each time

Tags: python, c++, numpy, ctypes

sorry for yet an other question about `dynamic module does not define init function`. I did go through older questions but I didn't find one which adress my case specifically enought.

I have a C++ library which should export several functions to python ( like ~5 functions defined in `extern "C" {}` block ). It works just fine when I recompile the library each time I import it. However, if I import it without recompilation it gives error `ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initmylib)`

The very simplified example which reproduce the same behaviour (error) looks like this:

C++ library code in file `mylib.cpp`

```
#include <math.h>
// there are some internal C++ functions and classes 
// which are not exported, but used in exported functions
extern "C"{
// one of the functions which should be accessible from python
void oscilator( double dt, int n, double * abuff, double * bbuff ){
    double a = abuff[0];
    double b = bbuff[0];
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++){
        a = a - b*dt;
        b = b + a*dt;
        abuff[i] = a;
        bbuff[i] = b;
    }
}
// there are also other functions but let's keep this example simple
// int initmylib( ){ return 0; } // some junk ... if this makes ctypes happy ?
}
```

python warper `mylib.py` of C++ library `mylib.cpp` :

```
import numpy as np
from   ctypes import c_int, c_double
import ctypes
import os

name='mylib'
ext='.so'  # if compited on linux .so on windows .dll

def recompile( 
        LFLAGS="",
        #FFLAGS="-Og -g -Wall"
        FFLAGS="-std=c++11 -O3 -ffast-math -ftree-vectorize"
    ):
    import os
    print " ===== COMPILATION OF : "+name+".cpp"
    print  os.getcwd()
    os.system("g++ "+FFLAGS+" -c -fPIC "+name+".cpp -o "+name+".o"+LFLAGS)
    os.system("g++ "+FFLAGS+" -shared -Wl,-soname,"+name+ext+" -o "+name+ext+" "+name+".o"+LFLAGS)

# this will recompile the library if somebody delete it
if not os.path.exists("./"+name+ext ):
    recompile()

lib    = ctypes.CDLL("./"+name+ext )

array1d = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.double, ndim=1, flags='CONTIGUOUS')

# void oscilator( double dt, int n, double * abuff, double * bbuff )
lib.oscilator.argtypes = [ c_double, c_int, array1d, array1d ]
lib.oscilator.restype  = None
def oscilator( dt, a, b ):
    n  = len(a)
    lib.oscilator( dt, n, a, b )
```

python program `test.py` which imports `mylib`

```
import os
from pylab import *
from basUtils import * 

# this will delete all compiled files of the library to force recompilation
def makeclean( ):
    [ os.remove(f) for f in os.listdir(".") if f.endswith(".so") ]
    [ os.remove(f) for f in os.listdir(".") if f.endswith(".o") ]
    [ os.remove(f) for f in os.listdir(".") if f.endswith(".pyc") ]

# if I do makeclean() every time it works, if I do not it does not
#makeclean( )

import mylib

a=zeros(100)
b=zeros(100)
a[0] = 1

mylib.oscilator( 0.1, a, b )

plot( a )
plot( b )

show()
```

I was also trying to make ctypes happy by adding some `int initmylib( ){ return 0; }` function into `mylib.cpp` as you can see in the code above. however this will produce error `SystemError: dynamic module not initialized properly`

I don't have this issue when I compile example of [cos_doubles](https://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/interfacing_with_c/interfacing_with_c.html) from scipy lecture notes. However, this example works only If I want to import just one function with the same name as the name of the library. I want something more general.

Comment: eryksun > ah, thanks, you are right the filename of the compiled library is the problem. With `lib_mylib.so` works fine. Do you want to make reguler answer so I can accept it and close the question ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running `import imp; print imp.find_module('mylib')[1]`. Are you surprised that it picks mylib.so instead of mylib.py? The interpreter expects mylib.so to be an extension module, which for CPython 2.x should define an initialization function named `initmylib`. To avoid accidentally trying to import the shared library, either change the name to something like _mylib.so or mylib.1.0.so -- or just save the file in a directory that's not in `sys.path`.

Note that Windows extension modules are DLLs, but with a .pyd extension instead of .dll. So `import mylib` won't try to load mylib.dll.

Comment: eryksun > ah, thanks, you are right the filename of the compiled library is the problem. With lib_mylib.so works fine.