# Can I use dask.delayed on a function wrapped with ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes, dask, dask-delayed

The goal is to use `dask.delayed` to parallelize some 'embarrassingly parallel' sections of my code. The code involves calling a python function which wraps a c-function using `ctypes`. To understand the errors I was getting I wrote a very basic example.

The c-function:

```
double zippy_sum(double x, double y)
{
return x + y;
}
```

The python:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(n_workers = 4)
client

import os
import dask
import ctypes

current_dir = os.getcwd() #os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
_mod = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.join(current_dir, "zippy.so"))

_zippy_sum = _mod.zippy_sum
_zippy_sum.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double]
_zippy_sum.restype = ctypes.c_double

def zippy(x, y):

    z = _zippy_sum(x, y)

    return z

result = dask.delayed(zippy)(1., 2.)
result.compute()
```

The Traceback:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~/.edm/envs/evaxi3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/worker.py
>   in dumps_function(func)    3286         with _cache_lock:
>   -> 3287             result = cache_dumps[func]    3288     except KeyError:
>
> ~/.edm/envs/evaxi3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py
>   in **getitem**(self, key)    1517     def **getitem**(self, key):
>   -> 1518         value = super().**getitem**(key)    1519         self.data.move_to_end(key)
>
> ~/.edm/envs/evaxi3.6/lib/python3.6/collections/**init**.py in
>   **getitem**(self, key)
>       990             return self.**class**.**missing**(self, key)
>   --> 991         raise KeyError(key)
>       992     def **setitem**(self, key, item): self.data[key] = item
>
> KeyError: function zippy at 0x11ffc50d0
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~/.edm/envs/evaxi3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py
>   in dumps(x)
>        40             if b"**main**" in result:
>   ---> 41                 return cloudpickle.dumps(x, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
>        42             else:
>
> ~/.edm/envs/evaxi3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py
>   in dumps(obj, protocol)    1147         cp = CloudPickler(file,
>   protocol=protocol)
>   -> 1148         cp.dump(obj)    1149         return file.getvalue()
>
> ~/.edm/envs/evaxi3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py
>   in dump(self, obj)
>       490         try:
>   --> 491             return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
>       492         except RuntimeError as e:
>
> ~/.edm/envs/evaxi3.6/lib/python3.6/pickle.py in dump(self, obj)
>       408             self.framer.start_framing()
>   --> 409         self.save(obj)
>       410         self.write(STOP)
>
> ~/.edm/envs/evaxi3.6/lib/python3.6/pickle.py in save(self, obj,
>   save_persistent_id)
>       475         if f is not None:
>   --> 476             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
>       477             return
>
> ~/.edm/envs/evaxi3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py
>   in save_function(self, obj, name)
>       565         else:
>   --> 566             return self.save_function_tuple(obj)
>       567
>
> ~/.edm/envs/evaxi3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py
>   in save_function_tuple(self, func)
>       779             state['kwdefaults'] = func.**kwdefaults**
>   --> 780         save(state)
>       781         write(pickle.TUPLE)
>
> ~/.edm/envs/evaxi3.6/lib/python3.6/pickle.py in save(self, obj,
>   save_persistent_id)
>       475         if f is not None:
>   --> 476             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
>       477             return
>
> ~/.edm/envs/evaxi3.6/lib/python3.6/pickle.py in save_dict(self, obj)
>       820         self.memoize(obj)
>   --> 821         self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
>       822
>
> ~/.edm/envs/evaxi3.6/lib/python3.6/pickle.py in _batch_setitems(self,
>   items)
>       846                     save(k)
>   --> 847                     save(v)
>       848                 write(SETITEMS)
>
> ~/.edm/envs/evaxi3.6/lib/python3.6/pickle.py in save(self, obj,
>   save_persistent_id)
>       475         if f is not None:
>   --> 476             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
>       477             return
>
> ~/.edm/envs/evaxi3.6/lib/python3.6/pickle.py in save_dict(self, obj)
>       820         self.memoize(obj)
>   --> 821         self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
>       822
>
> ~/.edm/envs/evaxi3.6/lib/python3.6/pickle.py in _batch_setitems(self,
>   items)
>       851                 save(k)
>   --> 852                 save(v)
>       853                 write(SETITEM)
>
> ~/.edm/envs/evaxi3.6/lib/python3.6/pickle.py in save(self, obj,
>   save_persistent_id)
>       495             if reduce is not None:
>   --> 496                 rv = reduce(self.proto)
>       497             else:
>
> ValueError: ctypes objects containing pointers cannot be pickled

Unfortunately, I still do not understand the errors! I am just getting started with `dask` and only have some basic experience with `ctypes`. Does anyone have suggestions for how to tackle this, or even understanding what need to be tackled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you cannot serialise a function referencing a C-function in the closure or the arguments. However, if your function is in a module which is accessible to all workers, then you end up serialising just the module name, and python does the right thing.

module zippy.py (somewhere on your python PATH, perhaps the current directory for the example):

```
import os
import dask
import ctypes

current_dir = os.getcwd() #os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
_mod = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.join(current_dir, "zippy.so"))

_zippy_sum = _mod.zippy_sum
_zippy_sum.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double]
_zippy_sum.restype = ctypes.c_double

def zippy(x, y):

    z = _zippy_sum(x, y)

    return z
```

main script:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
import zippy
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # if running as a script, this is helpful
    client = Client(n_workers = 4)

result = dask.delayed(zippy.zippy)(1., 2.)
result.compute()
```

The other solution, if you don't want to make a module, is to do all your C imports and definitions within the function.

```
def zippy(x, y):
    _mod = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.join(current_dir, "zippy.so"))

    _zippy_sum = _mod.zippy_sum
    _zippy_sum.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double]
    _zippy_sum.restype = ctypes.c_double

    z = _zippy_sum(x, y)

    return z
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @mdurant. Interestingly, both work on the test case (zippy) but not on my actual use case. I modified the test case to be more like the use case (using the omp.h library, and taking parameters from additional modules), but it still runs. The use case fails with a `KilledWorker` error. Is this indicative of anything? I need to do some more research and experimentation before I can form more specific questions.

Comment: Note, from experience ... naming the module zippy.py and the c-library zippy.so in the same directory can lead to some frustrating import errors. Best to modify the library name, for example to _zippy.so. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455178/numpy-ctypes-dynamic-module-does-not-define-init-function-error-if-not-recompi) for related discussion.

Comment: Yes, that's fine - or indeed make a real package out of it. https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/killed.html suggests a segfault or library load error on the worker - see the worker logs (easier if you use the CLI).

Comment: ah yes the logs provide much more information than the traceback in my Jupyter notebook. Thanks for pointing that out. I will continue to debug that problem, but I will mark your reply as answering the original question.